# How to properly use future/actorSelection/resolveOne in Play app?

Tags: scala, playframework, future

Below is my code:

```
def runAsync(crewType: String) = Action.async {
    val temp: Future[Result] = Future(Crew.findCaptainByCrewType(crewType) match {
      case None =>
        BadRequest(s"Invalid crew name provided: $crewType")
      case Some(crew) =>
        system.actorSelection(s"/user/${crew.cptName}").resolveOne().map { actorRef =>
          Ok(println("hi hi"))
        }
    })

    temp
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work?

My objective is to have user pass in a name, which then I try to find an actor with that name using the actorSelection and resolveOne. I assume I am using it incorrectly?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActorSelection.resolveOne()`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSelection) returns a `Future[ActorRef]`, and because you are inside a `Future(...)` you get a `Future[Future[Result]]` in case of a valid crewname.

You can solve this by using `flatMap` in which case you should also return a `Future` in case of an invalid crewname (`None`).

Unrelated: You can also leave out the `temp` value and can replace the pattern matching on `Option` by [`Option.fold`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@fold[B]%28ifEmpty:=%3EB%29%28f:A=%3EB%29:B).

```
def runAsync(crewType: String) = Action.async {
  Future(Crew.findCaptainByCrewType(crewType)).flatMap( _.fold(
    Future.successful(BadRequest(s"Invalid crew name provided: $crewType"))
  )( crew => 
    system.actorSelection(s"/user/${crew.cptName}").resolveOne().map { 
      actorRef => Ok(println("hi hi")) // not sure you want println here
    }
  ))
}
```

Comment: sry, but i pasted this code, and im getting some very long type mismatch error. :(

Comment: im reading the code u wrote, n i think i undertand what youre doing so ill tinker with it and update if i can...

Comment: It seems I misremembered the exact syntax of `fold` (it's `fold(ifEmpty)(f)` instead of `fold(ifEmpty, f)`).

Comment: wow that still looks complicated to me since i am beginner at scala. this is very helpful!!! thank you!